# Determine whether the functional series is uniformly convergent

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

The functional series is given by;$$\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{\sin(jx)}{(2+x^2)^j} $$
I believe that for this question I should be using the Weierstrass M-Test. So far I have $$\frac{\vert \sin(jx)\vert}{\vert(2+x^2)^j\vert} \le \frac{1}{\vert (2+x^2)^j\vert} $$
but I am not really sure where to go from here, any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: $\qquad\dfrac1{|(2+x^2)^j|}=\dfrac1{(2+x^2)^j}\le\dfrac1{2^j} $, and the latter series converges. So ...

Comment: perfect, thank you!